# How can I replace 2-prong receptacles in a code compliant way?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I have some 2-prong non-grounding type receptacles, and I'd like to replace them with 3-prong grounding type receptacles.  According to National Electrical Code, what are my options?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the National Electrical code, you have a few options. Depending on the situation, there are a few code sections to pay attention to.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Article 406 - Receptacles, Cord Connectors, and Attachment Plugs (Caps)
>
> **406.4 General Installation Requirements.**
>
> **(D) Replacements.** Replacement of receptacles shall comply with 406.4(D)(1), (D)(2), and (D)(3) as applicable. Arc-fault circuit-interrupter and ground-fault circuit-interrupter type receptacles shall be installed in a readily accessible location.

## Where a Grounding Means Exists

If there is a grounding conductor in the box, or the box itself is properly grounded. Then a 3-prong grounding type receptacle should be installed, and the receptacle should be grounded using approved means.

> **(1) Grounding-Type Receptacles.** Where a grounding means exists in the receptacle enclosure or an equipment grounding conductor is installed in accordance with 250.130(C), grounding-type receptacles shall be used and shall be connected to the equipment grounding conductor in accordance with 406.4(C) or 250.130(C).

## Where No Grounding Means Exists

If there is not a grounding conductor in the box, and the box itself is not grounded.  There are a few options.

> **(2) Non–Grounding-Type Receptacles.** Where attachment to an equipment grounding conductor does not exist in the receptacle enclosure, the installation shall comply with (D)(2)(a), (D)(2)(b), or (D)(2)(c).

- You can simply replace the 2-prong receptacle with another 2-prong receptacle.

  > (a) A non–grounding-type receptacle(s) shall be permitted to be replaced with another non–grounding-type receptacle( s).
- You can replace the 2-prong receptacle with a ground-fault circuit interrupting device. Though the device must be labeled "No Equipment Ground", and a grounding conductor should not be connected to this or any downstream devices.

  > (b) A non–grounding-type receptacle(s) shall be permitted to be replaced with a ground-fault circuit interrupter-type of receptacle(s). These receptacles shall be marked “No Equipment Ground.” An equipment grounding conductor shall not be connected from the ground-fault circuit interrupter-type receptacle to any outlet supplied from the ground-fault circuit-interrupter receptacle.
- You can install a ground-fault circuit interrupting device upstream, and install a 3-prong receptacle in this location. Though you'll have to label the receptacle "No Equipment Ground", and "GFCI Protected". No equipment grounding conductor should be connected to the receptacle.

  > (c) A non–grounding-type receptacle(s) shall be permitted to be replaced with a grounding-type receptacle(s) where supplied through a ground-fault circuit interrupter. Grounding-type receptacles supplied through the ground-fault circuit interrupter shall be marked “GFCI Protected” and “No Equipment Ground.” An equipment grounding conductor shall not be connected between the grounding-type receptacles.

## Provide Other Protection Where Required

### Where GFCI Protection is Required

If ground-fault circuit interruption is required, a ground-fault circuit interruption device should be installed. These devices do not require a grounding conductor, so can be installed in a circuit without a ground.

> **(3) Ground-Fault Circuit Interrupters.** Ground-fault circuit-interrupter protected receptacles shall be provided where replacements are made at receptacle outlets that are required to be so protected elsewhere in this Code.

### Where AFCI Protection is Required

If arc-fault circuit interruption is required, an arc-fault circuit interruption device should be installed. These devices do not require a grounding conductor, so can be installed in a circuit without a ground.

> **(4) Arc-Fault Circuit-Interrupter Protection.** Where a receptacle outlet is supplied by a branch circuit that requires arc-fault circuit interrupter protection as specified elsewhere in this Code, a replacement receptacle at this outlet shall be one of the following:
>
> (1) A listed outlet branch circuit type arc-fault circuit-interrupter receptacle.
>
> (2) A receptacle protected by a listed outlet branch circuit type arc-fault circuit interrupter type receptacle.
>
> (3) A receptacle protected by a listed combination type arc-fault circuit interrupter type circuit breaker.

### Where Tamper-Resistant Receptacles are Required

If tamper-resistant receptacles are required, a tamper-resistant device should be installed.

> **(5) Tamper-Resistant Receptacles.** Listed tamper-resistant receptacles shall be provided where replacements are made at receptacle outlets that are required to be tamper-resistant elsewhere in this Code.

### Where Weather-Resistant Receptacles are Required

If weather-resistant receptacles are required, a weather-resistant device should be installed.

> **(6) Weather-Resistant Receptacles.** Weather-resistant receptacles shall be provided where replacements are made at receptacle outlets that are required to be so protected elsewhere in this Code.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I found is to install a GFCI at the first receptacle upstream from the rest of the receptacles on a branch circuit....( Grounding the GFCI by running a ground wire to the nearest ground).... This allows for protection to the consumer without needing to replace all the wiring....(most economical)....