# Integrating into knob-and-tube wiring: okay to borrow a ground

Tags: electrical, grounding, knob-and-tube, grounding-and-bonding

I have a mixture of knob-and-tube and NM-B.
If I'm extending from knob and tube, but I have a (different) an NM-B circuit nearby, is it technically allowable to ground via ground wire in the other cable?
If not, what is the right way to do it?  (Please don't tell me to replace all the knob and tube -- it's not going to happen.)

Comment: @NiallC.   Thanks.   So if I understand this, bottom line is, yes it is allowed, right?

Comment: @NiallC. :   Fortunately, I don't make a habit of adding rooms to my house.   Oh, wait a second, does three rooms in 7 years count.   I guess.   But this is the first case where it is not practical to add completely new wiring to the panel.

Comment: @ThePopMachine No. You cannot borrow the grounding conductor from another branch circuit.  I guess I need to update the answer on the other question to make that clear.

Comment: @Tester101:   If you say no, then what does this part mean?
For replacement of ... branch-circuit extensions only in existing installations that do not have an equipment grounding conductor in the branch circuit, connections shall be permitted as
(C) Nongrounding Receptacle Replacement or Branch Circuit Extensions. The equipment grounding conductor of a grounding-type receptacle or a branch-circuit extension shall be permitted to be connected to any of the following:
(1) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode system [...]
(2) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode conductor

Comment: @ThePopMachine The grounding electrode system (of which the grounding electrode is a part), is a system of conductors used to connect the service equipment to the earth.  Equipment grounding conductors (those found in branch circuits), are **not** part of the grounding electrode system.

Comment: @Tester101:   Then what are my options?   Is it impossible to add a ground to existing ungrounded cabling without replacing it completely?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I don't know what to tell you... Not everything is easy. In fact, doing things the right way is typically more difficult. That's why there's so much hacked together crap out there. Why do you need a grounding conductor anyway?  The information in [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/36427/33) might be helpful.

Comment: @Tester101:   Well the circuit in question is all the outlets and lights in a new garage.   So I'm somewhat uncomfortable with not having ground because there could be a lot of different power tools.   It will be GFCI'd anyhow, but surely an imperfect ground is better than none...

Comment: @ThePopMachine If it's a new garage, why is there knob and tube wiring? Run a new circuit from the panel to the garage, or better yet, feed a subpanel in the garage from the main panel. You should not be tapping an existing circuit to supply a new garage.

Comment: "okay to borrow a ground" ... only if you promise to give it back.

Answer (score -1):

Not to be snarky, but, if you mess up plumbing you get wet and stinky. If you mess up electricity, you get burned or dead. Is it really worth the risk?

As you touch the old unsafe and code fail stuff, replace it. No need to do everything at once.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question or give any references. It may be a bad thing to do, but without any references or explanation, it's just an opinion.

Comment: For the opposite view see http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/20279/5960