# non grounded outlets converted to gfi

Tags: receptacle, gfci

If I have 5 old outlets that are not grounded(but installed in old plaster walls that I dont want to disturb) can I wire a gfi at lead of circuit and protect the others downstream. I have access to 1 of the  outlets, and can reach the wiring of the others from under the house.Or should I fish new wire through the walls ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

You can protect the downstream receptacles, by supplying them from the LOAD side of a GFCI device.

Or you could install new cable.

Comment: Could you please give a code reference that allow the change of a two wire with no ground receptacle too a  three wire grounder receptacle.

Comment: @WarLoki [406.4(D)(2)(b) and (c)](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/36427/33).

Comment: @Tester101 This is permitted as long as you label the non grounded outlets with the "no equipment ground" label that comes provided with most GFCI outlets.

Comment: @Kris That's true, technically. unfortunately it is almost never done in a residential situation, especially by DIY Electricians.

Comment: @Tester101 I agree with you about the code, but that label has got to be there.