# Are existing non-tamper-resistant outlets grandfathered in NEC?

Tags: nec

My residence is a town home built in the late '90s, thus having non-tamper-resistant outlets.  I assume that they are grandfathered in NEC?  Am I required, by NEC, to install tamper-resistant when replacing an outlet?

Comment: Also, not all outlets, even if swapped out, are required to be tamper-resistant.  There are currently four exceptions in the NEC, but your local authority may be different.  Those exceptions are 1) any outlet over 5 1/2 ft. 2) any outlet behind appliances. 3) any duplex outlet readily accessible but is plugged in by two appliances, or a single yoke outlet that is plugged in by one appliance. 4) Or any outlet not in a habitable area of the house like attics, crawl spaces, and maybe outdoors.  I say maybe outdoors because of habitable cabanas or other similar areas.

Comment: To where on the receptacle is that 5 1/2 feet measured?

Comment: the code doesn't specify that.  It just says receptacles 5 1/2 ft above the floor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you're **not** making changes, there's no requirement to swap them out. If you **are** changing out the receptacles for any reason, you'll have to install tamper resistant receptacles.  You cannot replace the receptacles with non-tamper resistant receptacles (*technically*).

Comment: I think you answered it more fully [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36426/how-can-i-replace-2-prong-receptacles-in-a-code-compliant-way)

Comment: Thanks to both Tester101 and bib for their answers.  They cover the original question well.